# Dryer 220 outlet having issues with voltage to get new dryer running

Tags: electrical

When I check the voltage of L1 and L2 combined I get 240 volts.

I then check L1 to neutral and get 120v; however, when I check L2 to the neutral I’m getting 0 volts?

I’ve replaced the plug and breaker and still keeps reading the same.

This is a new dryer and the old one was operating just fine.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Is this a 3-prong or a 4-prong dryer outlet?

Comment: Where are you checking? Is this the same question from a day or 2 back?

Comment: Is there a ground wire in there?  Or can one easily be added?  Problem aside, this is a great time to upgrade from the obsolete, dangerous and illegal-unless-grandfathered 3-prong receps, to the modern and safe 4-prong.

Comment: Check the voltage with a small load, e.g. a 10 kohm resistor across the line. The voltages you are recording are not possible unless you're picking up some capacitive coupling.